# reusing a device in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have a program that uses cv::Videocapture to stream a video from a webcm, my question is, is there any possibility to reopen or resuing this device in the same program after releasing it ?? and that witout closing the programm!! 
thanks .

Comment: What about redoing the same operations you did to initialize and record in the first place? Logical, no?

Answer (score 3):

```
VideoCapture cap(0);

//do stuff

cap.release();



cap.open(0);

// do stuff

cap.release();
```

Comment: I tryoed this before asking my question and the program crashes